# Unable to get response from a POST request. Laravel and jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have the following code in a ".blade.php" file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ans_buttton").on('click', function(){
  $.post("http://localhost:8000/answer", {round: "{{$round}}", sno: "{{$sno}}"}, function(data, status){
      $("#answer").html(data);
  });
});
});
```

And the Route is as follows.

```
Route::post('/answer', function(){
$round = Input::get('round');
$sno = Input::get('sno');
$ans = question::where('round', $round)->where('sno', $sno)->first();
echo "$ans->answer";
});
```

I get a 500 Internal Error.
What have I missed?

I'm a beginner. Please help out!

Answer (score 0):

change `$ans = question::where('round', $round)->where('sno', $sno)->first();` to

```
$ans = question::where('round','=', $round)->where('sno','=', $sno)->first();
```

use whatever operator you want.